# Choosing the adapter SendTo uses to transmit a multicast frame

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-3.0, udp, multicast

I have a C# .net 3.5 application where I use `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendTo()` to send a UDP frame to the multicast address `224.0.100.1`. I then use `BeginReceiveFrom()` on the same socket to listen for all the responses.

But, on systems where there is more than one network adapter, it seems to be random on which adapter the UDP packet is sent.

How can I allow the user the option to select the adapter that will be used and force `SendTo()` to use that address?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822968/win32-sockets-forcing-ip-packets-to-leave-physical-interfaces-when-sending-to

Comment: @PaulH Did it work now? I am facing a smiliar problem.

Comment: @Gobliins Yes, it works when I use Socket.Bind(). If that doesn't work for you, post a new question with your code.

Comment: Yea, i figured out i should use the Socket class not the UdpClient wrapper around. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Socket.Bind()` to set the local endpoint before sending.